# Aggregating all unique values of each column of data frame

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a large data frame (1616610 rows, 255 columns) and I need to paste together the unique values of each column based on a key.

For example:

```
> data = data.frame(a=c(1,1,1,2,2,3),
              b=c("apples", "oranges", "apples", "apples", "apples", "grapefruit"),
              c=c(12, 22, 22, 45, 67, 28), 
              d=c("Monday", "Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Tuesday"))
> data
  a          b  c         d
1 1     apples 12    Monday
2 1    oranges 22    Monday
3 1     apples 22    Monday
4 2     apples 45   Tuesday
5 2     apples 67 Wednesday
6 3 grapefruit 28   Tuesday
```

What I need is to aggregate each unique value in each of the 255 columns, and return a new data frame with comma separators for each unique value. Like this:

```
  a               b      c                  d
1 1 apples, oranges 12, 22             Monday
2 2          apples 45, 67 Tuesday, Wednesday
3 3      grapefruit     28           Thursday
```

I have tried using `aggregate`, like so:

```
output <- aggregate(data, by=list(data$a), paste, collapse=", ")
```

but for a data frame this size, it has been too time-intensive (hours), and often times I have to kill the process all together. On top of that, this will aggregate all values and not only the unique ones. Does anyone have any tips on:

1) how to improve the time of this aggregation for large data sets

2) then get the unique values of each field

BTW, this is my first post on SO, so thanks for your patience.

Comment: For that size, you're probably going to need `data.table`. I'm not great with its syntax, but there are people here who are.

Comment: thanks @alistaire. I have heard good things about `data.table` for large data sets, and have tried working with it, but I can't seem to figure out the syntax for this problem.

Comment: Thanks @G.Grothendieck ! That worked well

Comment: @G.Grothendieck can you rewrite this as an answer so I can mark solved? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moved from comments:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(data)
dt[, lapply(.SD, function(x) toString(unique(x))), by = a]
```

giving:

```
   a               b      c                  d
1: 1 apples, oranges 12, 22             Monday
2: 2          apples 45, 67 Tuesday, Wednesday
3: 3      grapefruit     28            Tuesday
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do the following with `dplyr`

**Edit 1**

**Updated answer** which eliminates the deprecation warning caused by using `summarise_each` (as of dplyr 0.7.0). This uses `summarise` & `across` instead of `summarise_each`.

```
library(dplyr)

func_paste <- function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ', ')
data %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), func_paste))

# Without "func_paste", using paste directly (from Alistaire's comment).
data %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ paste(unique(.), collapse = ', ')))

## # A tibble: 3 × 4
##       a b               c      d
##   <dbl> <chr>           <chr>  <chr>
## 1     1 apples, oranges 12, 22 Monday
## 2     2 apples          45, 67 Tuesday, Wednesday
## 3     3 grapefruit      28     Tuesday
```

**Previous answer**, which will cause a deprecated warning (as of dplyr 0.7.0)

```
func_paste <- function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ', ')
data %>%
    group_by(a) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(func_paste))

##      a               b      c                  d
##  (dbl)           (chr)  (chr)              (chr)
##1     1 apples, oranges 12, 22             Monday
##2     2          apples 45, 67 Tuesday, Wednesday
##3     3      grapefruit     28            Tuesday

# Without "func_paste", using paste directly (from Alistaire's comment).
data %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(paste(unique(.), collapse = ', ')))
```

Comment: In one, `data %>% group_by(a) %>% summarise_each(funs(paste(unique(.), collapse = ', ')))`. It's slower than the original `aggregate`, though it does return the correct result, at least.

Comment: @alistaire Thanks for testing and removing the need for a separate function. It would be hard to beat a `data.table` solution for running speed.